# Working with files in intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to work with files in intelij in this case txt files. I have found if I distinguish the whole file path eg

```
"C:\\Users\\benji\\java\\Project\\files\\newfile.txt"
```

Works but if I try

```
"files/newfile.txt"
```

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: files\newfile.txt
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:99)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

the file is there I was hoping someone would be able to shed some light thank you.

Comment: I suggest you check your working directory in your run configuration. I suggest you print out `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

Comment: Or, similar, `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath())`

Comment: Thank you. You have helped me a lot =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try

```
"files/newfile.txt"
```

this is short hand for

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.pathSeparatorChar + "files/newfile.txt";
```

whether you have used `/` or `\\` shouldn't matter under windows, but you have to make sure the current working direct is what you expect it to be.  It can be set in your `Run Configuration`.

To check this you can add

```
System.out.println("user.dir= " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: "Shouldn't matter" under Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your input I changed my file structure so there wasn't a lot of projects going on and it works now =) thank you very much you helped me out